# Any logs of if/when "at" jobs were executed?

Tags: linux, centos, cron, syslog

I've setup a couple of "at" jobs to execute at specific times on CentOS 5.
This morning I don't see these commands in the queue ("atq"), as expected, but I also don't see were can I check whether the daemon responsible to execute them did this on time or had any issues.
Unfortunately I didn't log enough info from the scripts themselves.
Any ideas?

Comment: To those who marked this as a duplicate - the pointed answer was about setting up logging before the command is executed. My question is about digging up logs after the fact.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From looking at the source of the 'at' program (from the CentOS 5.3 source repository) , it looks like it is indeed logging to syslog, but only fatal errors regarding the at daemon itself are logged (for example, if you try to run 2 at daemons at the same time).

However, process executions, resulting return code and standard error/output are not logged to syslog at all. Even when turning on debug (which requires recompilation) the log messages are not very informative (for end users) and write something like :

atd[24116]: pid 24121 exited with status 0.

Which will not help you a lot in identifying which command was ran, by which user or what was its standard output/error.

atd does send an email notification to the user who requested the command, in case the command had failed, or produced anything in it's standard output/error. But for commands that succeed without any output , no mail is sent. You can change that using the -m flag.

From at(1):

```
-m Send mail to the user when the job has completed even if there was no output.
```

Borrowed from Tom Feiner's answer from almost an [identical question](https://serverfault.com/questions/19379/logging-atd-messages-via-syslog).

Comment: At typically logs to syslog on all *nix systems I've encountered.  The facility may vary: there isn't a dedicated one.  I've seen `daemon` and `cron` used

Comment: Thanks for both of you for your answers. You confirmed what I suspected - if my commands don't have extra-logging then at's own logging isn't going to help.

However - grep'ing for "atd" through the compressed "/var/log/messages*.gz" I found hints for the execution happening by form of PAM logs at the expected times. Although this isn't conclusive at least something happened when it was expected.