# Show list of jobs completed using 'at'

Tags: linux

Is there a way to show all of the jobs which were completed using the `at` command?  I'm trying to debug a problem related to a command scheduled with `at` and I don't think it's my application, so I'm wondering if it might be the OS.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/19379/logging-atd-messages-via-syslog) please, it's already answered here. The atd daemon is logging only fatal errors of daemon via syslog.